# html2canvas works on jsfiddle but doesn't work on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

based on https://jsfiddle.net/Sq7hg/3120/
it's pure JS - without any library - but it works on `jsfiddle`
on my site - and also here - it doesn't work
I'm getting error - `html2canvas is not defined`
please help

```js
html2canvas([document.getElementById('mydiv')], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = data;
        document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);
    }
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"><p>text!</p></div>
<br><br>
 <div id="canvas"><p>Canvas:</p></div>
 <div id="image"><p>Image:</p></div>
```

Comment: html2canvas is a library, you've to load it.

Comment: it is not loaded on jsfiddle  - isn't it ?

Comment: _"it's pure JS - without any library"_ - The "Resources" section to the left tells a different story ;)

Comment: @Andreas - I see, thanks a lot. Any clever reason for `No-Library(Pure JS)` ?

Comment: @provance — That's for adding a small selection of common libraries as opposed to custom resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you are not importing html2canvas anywhere. You can have a [look at the docs](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started) and follow along.

You will need to add an import in your js.

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

As the docs state, this is if you installed it via npm in your project.